# How to only run a gulp.task locally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, gulp-task

I have the following gulp function:

```
// TODO: Comment for production.
gulp.task('startServer', function() {
  return connect.server({
    root: './dist',
    port: 8080
  });
});
```

Every time I pull it to work on it locally, I have to uncomment the code and then comment it back when I push to prod.  I have to do something similar to this in a few files.  Is there a clever way to avoid this hassle and being able to pull/push code without having to comment/uncomment all of this for every single branch I work on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use gulp code to start server . You can run local and production server using express nodejs.

Comment: This app already relies heavily on gulp.  Just looking for a workaround for this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

On your production server, the NODE_ENV environment variable should be set to production (`NODE_ENV=production`). So you can add a conditional to your gulp file to check whether you are running it on the production server or not:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  gulp.task('startServer', function() {
    return connect.server({
      root: './dist',
      port: 8080
    });
  });
}
```